# Boto3 list_append a value to overwrite a null value in a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am writing a small lambda function to update a `game` item in my DynamoDB. My `game` item has a `participants` attribute which is a list consisting of the `participant_id` of each participant in the game. When a game doesn't have any participants yet (i.e. a round later in the bracket) the list will hold 2 `null` values:

[image: Empty participant list]

I would like to overwrite the `null` values with a string each time I add a new participant. Currently I am able to append a new String to the list but the `null` values remain:

[image: After adding a participant]

***How can I overwrite one of the 2 null values with a string using boto3?*** 
(i.e. to where it looks like `["participantOneId", Null]` after adding one participant and `["participantOneId", "participantTwoId"]` after adding both participants)
This is my current implementation:

```
import boto3
import json

dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
gamesTable = dynamodb.Table('games')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  # get "next_game_id" and "winner_id" from the event body
  updated_next_game = gamesTable.update_item(
      Key={'id': next_game_id },
      UpdateExpression="SET participants = list_append(participants, :i)",
      ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':i': [winner_id],
      },
      ReturnValues="ALL_NEW"
  )
```

Comment: Why store two Null values in the first place?

Comment: Good point @jarmod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to append anything to the list, then you don't want to use `list_append`. Something like this should work fine:

```
UpdateExpression="SET participants[0] = <whatever>"
```

and/or

```
UpdateExpression="SET participants[1] = <whatever>"
```

(If you won't know in advance which of the two elements you need to set, you can always use [`if_not_exists`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.PreventingAttributeOverwrites).)